# Table body, head overlaps and width of the table is not expanding

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-table, fixed-header-tables

I have created an application in angularjs using ngtable, since I need the table head to be fixed I tried using  `position:fixed;` so that the head is fixed but the problem is that now the body and head overlaps also the width of the table is not expanding

My code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghjc22as/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    <table border="1" ng-table="mytable" id="myTable" class="ScrollArea">
        <tbody ng-repeat="peop in $groups">
            <tr ng-repeat="people in peop.data">
                <td sortable="id" data-title="'Id'">{{people.id}}</td>
                <td sortable="desig" data-title="'Desig'">{{people.desig}}</td>
                <td sortable="name" data-title="'Name'">{{people.name}}</td>
                <td sortable="place" data-title="'Place'">{{people.place}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#myTable thead
{
    position:fixed;
}
.ScrollArea
{
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: why you don't try using ui-grid(ng-grid)?http://ui-grid.info/

Comment: we are using ng-table....

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove **position fixed** in #myTable thead

and remove display: block; in .scrollArea.

Comment: then i cant set theheight to table, also the sticky header http://jsfiddle.net/ghjc22as/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add cellpadding to change width of the table. and add top/bottom to the thead to solve the overlap.

Comment: can you just give me a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TMDineshUID/ghjc22as/8/ im trying this in another way.is it okay to you?